# jscroll (lazy loading) deletes pagination

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using a nice plugin [jScroll](http://jscroll.com/) for infinite scrolling, the examples are easy and straight forward, but it doesnt work right for me though.

The script for scroll is:

```
$('.infinite-scroll').jscroll({
        debug: true,
        autoTrigger: false,
        loadingHtml: '<img src="css/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading" /> Loading...',
        padding: 20,
        nextSelector: 'a.jscroll-next:last',
        contentSelector: '.scrolltable'
    });
```

it works fine loads second page, but not the rest, in the console it says it cannt find the next selector therefore its terminating. When I check the source, I find that the paging div is totally removed when you scroll to the second page, any ideas ?

Comment: Are you including the next link in your second page HTML? That is, the initial HTML should include the link to the second page, the second to the third, etc.

Comment: @Jimothy Yes, but it gets totally removed when I scroll down

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like jScroll is not finding your `nextSelector` within the returned content for the second page. If `a.jscroll-next:last` is not contained within `.scrolltable` of the returned content, then jScroll will self-destroy.

As for the paging div being removed from the DOM, this happens for each page once the next page is loading. What you may be seeing is the pagination being removed from the first page, and your second page does not contain your pagination div within `.scrolltable`.

See the line linked to below where jScroll removes the pagination's parent container:

https://github.com/pklauzinski/jscroll/blob/master/jquery.jscroll.js#L163